# Why is the Relative layout is given as default in main.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have seen the difference i.e in the latest android SDK versions the default layout given in the main.xml file is Relative Layout.

What is the reason behind that..Is using relative layout recommended to be used more than linear layout?If yes...Please explain..

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: It used to be `LinearLayout`, then `RelativeLayout`, I guess `GridLayout` is next. Its just what they set in default template. `RelativeLayout` is more generic for beginning with.

Answer (score 2):

To provide us the more flexibility and freedom in programming of UI.

**LinearLayout** arranges elements side by side either horizontally or vertically(rows vs columns).

**RelativeLayout** is a layout manager that helps you arrange your UI elements based on some rule. You can specify thisngs like: align this to parents left edge, place this to the left/right of this elements etc.

Answer (score 2):

As mobile apps are going with much more interactive and complex UIs, RelativeLayout helps in building those UI plus reducing the layout hierarchy considerably with so many tags provided.

This improves the performance of the app too.

Comment: yes, as a good approach to build android layouts, one must always try to keep the layout hierarchy as low as possible. coz at last they are gonna be initialized at run time and eats up memory.